# How to .ToUpper() each element of an array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I have this LINQ expression:

```
string[] x = originalString.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(y => y.Substring(0,1).ToUpper());
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Cannot convert source type 'void' to target type 'string[]'
```

I think I get the error; The ForEach returns void. I'm not sure how to fix it and still keep this a LINQ expression.

How do I split `originalString` and then loop over the elements in the array, applying `.ToUpper()` on each element AND do it all in a LINQ expression?

Comment: In general, whenever you do `ToArray` or `ToList` it should only be to *store* a materialized result somewhere. If you're using it to **abuse** a method from Array or `List<T>`, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string[] x = originalString.Split(',')
                           .Select(y => y.Substring(0,1).ToUpper())
                           .ToArray();
```

Should do the thing - get the first letter of each word, uppercase.

But I think what you're really looking for is:

```
string[] x = originalString.Split(',')
                           .Select(y => y.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + y.Substring(1))
                           .ToArray();
```

That should capitalize elements which were split from input (sounds much more useful).

Example of usage for second query:

```
 string originalString = "TestWord,another,Test,word,World,Any";
```

Output:

```
TestWord
Another
Test
Word
World
Any
```

Comment: Yes, I want to capitalize the first letter of each element and keep the entire word.

Comment: So the second query should do the thing!

Answer (score 1):

Use a projection:

```
string[] x = originalString.Split(',')
    .Select(y => y.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()).ToArray();
```